# Prepositional phrases

Tags: prepositions

> It was drawing to an end now; but the evening was even warm, and I sat
>   at work in the schoolroom (1) with **the window open**. (Jane Eyre)
>
> Presently the chambers gave up their fair tenants one after another:
>   each came out gaily and airily, (2) with **dress that gleamed lustrous
>   through the dusk**. (Jane Eyre)

The two prepositional phrases each have (1) a small clause (Bas Aart’s term), (2) a noun and the relative. How do you call these in grammatical terms?

Comment: Hi, I'm just going through posts which have "How do you call....?" in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing yours to *“What do you call these....?”* Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We don’t.  You’re over-analysing all this.

In both cases you have an object of a preposition that has further modifications, in the first case an adjective and in the second a subordinate clause.

Just leave it at that and move on. There is nothing more to be gained by inventing new vocabulary and classification here.

Comment: Yours is a good one, i think. And the modifications could be at the same line with 'completers' that someone said: for your information, I have my own mother tongue language grammar books beside this computer, for conferencing now and then. Don't you need the necessity? That's my way of doing Language and Usage. Don't dare intervene my own method.